# Search As in IOS8 Calender app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I'm wondering how i can achieve the same search function as in the calender app. When u click the RightBarButton then a new navigationBar with the searchBar animate on top of the existing and hwn u click cancel it will animate away. I guess this is a UISearchDisplayController which appears on the top, but how can i do something like this?

Here u see an illustration so when u click searchButton searchBar appear from the top and when u press done it animates away again.

[image]

Comment: I hope you won't be down voted for not using freehand circles http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to show the search bar by using:

At tap:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        _collectionView.center = CGPointMake(160, 700);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self presentViewController:clockTappedController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
```

In viewWillAppear:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            _collectionView.center = CGPointMake(160, 528);

        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
```

I've used it for collection view, but i think that you can do the same using the searchbar.

Loading the searchbar off of the screen and then get it slide down at tap on the icon. When you tap on done you put again the searchbar off the screen.

Comment: So could u explain what do your collectionView do? when u click a button a collectionView slide in or what?

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is the animation in viewWillAppear, i've the animation at tap that do like this: `[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [_collectionView setAlpha:0.5];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            _collectionView.center = CGPointMake(160, 700);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self presentViewController:clockTappedController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }];
    }];`

Comment: So the animation provides an alpha animation and a movement of the collection view out of the screen and then move again the collection at his place.